# Is there a way to use the Python package import path as class specifier?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given the following file-structure:

```
Car/
     __input__.py
     Line.py
     Country.py
```

Where Line.py contains a class:

```
class Line:     
    def __init__(self,name):
    self.name = name
```

I know I can use the class 'Line' with something like this:

```
from Car.Line import Line
line = Line("Chevy")
print str(line)
```

However, for various reasons I was hoping to be able to use the inherent package import path when specifying the class name, *and* was hoping I'd be able to bring everything in a package, in one fell swoop.

i.e., I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
import Car
line = Car.Line("chevy")
country = Car.Country("chevy")
```

I'd guessed that this would work:

```
from Car.Line import Line as Car.Line
```

But that doesn't work: Python doesn't like the dot in the alias.

I've tried several other things, but not been able to come up with what I'd guessed ought to be possible.

I know there's discussions out there about whether or not all classes ought to be able to into a separate class file, and that's not what I'm really trying to achieve.  I am hoping to be able to segregate some of my classes together usefully in the filesystem, while being able to address them elegantly.

Is this something I can do in Python ? Can I get even halfway there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple once you grokked a simple truth about modules: All the names you define in them are by default exported for importing. In fact you need to actively suppress this behaviour using the `__all__` special name.

So to achieve what you want, all you need to do is to import the desired things into the `Car` namespace. Which is formed by the `__init__.py` within `Car`.

So in this file, you do

```
 from .Line import Line
```

That's it. I would suggest though you take a look at Pep8, the Python naming conventions, and stick to it. This would mean that your module/package-names become lower-case, and a lot of other hints that make understanding by others (such as me on StackOverflow) easier.

Comment: Thanks deets - your solution worked a charm. I will take a look a closer look at Pep8 - but I have to confess - I found it a tad too dictatorial.  I wanted to flag your reply as an answer, or at least upvote it - sadly, it seems I don't have those privileges yet.  Thanks again !

Comment: deets - it helped greatly.  I just didn't see how to mark the question as answered.  I do now, I *think* ;-)